# What does "for not being bigger" mean here?

Tags: prepositions

I am reading a book about Tim Walker and get quite confused when I read this yesterday, Here is the context:

So here then are the truths of that Vogue picture from 1947: It was staged by a German émigré painter, whose accent rendered him only partially intelligible in his adopted country; the hawk was not, strictly speaking, native to the United Kingdom and certainly not to London; the portrait was taken by an American on secondment to England, who did not care about painters or painting (Clifford Coffin cared even less about the British landscape, once observed haranguing the standing stones of Stonehenge for ***not being bigger***). Despite appearances, there’s little ‘English’ about it at all, just the suggestion of it. How potent for one photographer suggestion can be.

Anyone could talk anything on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

"[H]aranguing the standing stones of Stonehenge for not being bigger" means Coffin was giving a prolonged negative criticism of the stones, probably verbally and as if speaking *to* them, on the basis that they were not any bigger than they actually are.  The intent seems to be to portray Coffin as absurd and unappreciative, for Stonehenge's stones neither hear nor care, and they are quite large enough that they should impress anyone, especially when one appreciates how long ago Stonhenge was erected.